# Can't load "Show more" in a webpage using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to load "Show More" using selenium in python. However, the code is running and executing fine but I am getting 'Message' and 'complete'(this I understand) in python console. 
Also, the webpage I am trying to open is opening but as soon as I try to scroll down it is showing a window, "This Safari window is remotely controlled by an automated test." Even though I click 'continue session' and again try to scroll down the page, it again shows the same window.

I am working on MacBook​ Air and using Safari as a browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time

browser = webdriver.Safari(executable_path = '/usr/bin/safaridriver')

browser.get('https://www.nytimes.com/search?endDate=20190331&query=cybersecurity&sort=newest&startDate=20180401')

Show_more_xpath = '//*[@id="site-content"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/button'

while True:
    try:
        show_more = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@type="button"], and contains(.,"Show More")')
        time.sleep(2)
        show_more.click()
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
print("Complete")
time.sleep(10)

browser.quit()
```

I want to load "Show More" automatically to get all the entries.
The ultimate goal is to scrape the page using beautifulsoup.

Answer (score 0):

driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Have search feedback? Let us know what you think.'])[1]/following::button[1]").click()

Answer (score 0):

To click on **`Show More`** Button do the followings.

Click on `I Accept` button first and then use `WebdriverWait` and element_to_be_clickable to wait for for element to be clickable and then the use action class to click on the specific button.Try to below code hope this will work for you.

```
browser.get('https://www.nytimes.com/search?endDate=20190331&query=cybersecurity&sort=newest&startDate=20180401')

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'I Accept')]").click()

while True:
    try:
        show_more = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@type="button"][contains(.,"Show More")]')))
        ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(show_more).click().perform()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break

print("Complete")
time.sleep(10)

browser.quit()
```

You need to have following imports to execute above code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: There is no "I Accept" button in this site? It is showing error: I_accept_xpath = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'I Accept')]").click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: Why don’t you copy my code? If you see you have used find_elements it should be find_element

Comment: I tried by copying your code but still, it is showing the error in "I Accept" part.

Comment: What if you comment that line.Have you tested that?